# Match regex except if it ends like a specified string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match everything before the top property except if it has style.top. This is for old browsers so negative lookbehind is not allowed. Any ideas?

Tried a lot of different strategies already. Not great at regex.

Comment: Is it not possible to filter the list of matches afterwards with a simple string comparison?

Comment: So any matches will change the code, so I can't make another match to check for only style.top @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: Do you only want to match what is in between parenthesis? Can you update the question with the expected matches?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Done! Yeah, so it matches everything in parenthesis but does not match if it is "style.top"

Comment: @Theodore Like this with a capture group? `\(((?!\.style\b)[^()]+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/kT2kcv/1

Comment: Or if there has to be `.top` then `\(((?!\.style\b)[^()]*\.top\b[^()]*)\)` https://regex101.com/r/Kd1N9b/1

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be in brackets. So notice xestyle.top is suppose to match but not style.top. Thank you for helping with this :) I've been stuck on it for hours. But it's to match all objects properties that end with *.top, except style.top is the gist.

Comment: @Theodore So you mean you want to match the whole string, as long as it does not contain `.style`  and it should contain `.top` ?

Comment: It should match any string with `x.top` where x can be any string and as many time ends with `.` But if it's `style.top` then it doesn't match.

Comment: So like `^(?!.*\.style\b).*\btop\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/IXzJt8/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Nope, I added an image to show what needs to be matched. This is a hard one. :(

Comment: @Thefourthbird We added some tests: https://regexr.com/7ql5i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:.*[^$\s])?\bstyle\W*\.top\b).*\.top\b.*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `.*[^$\s]` Match optional characters followed by a non whitespace char other than `$`
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
  - `\bstyle\W*\.top\b` Match the word `style` followed by optional non word characters and then `.top`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `.*\btop\b.*` Match the string containing  `.top`

See the [regex tests](https://regexr.com/7ql9g).

---

If it should be `style` or `(style)` then:

```
^(?!(?:.*[^$\s])?(?:\bstyle|\(style\))\.top\b).*\.top\b.*
```

Comment: OMG! This is close but a lot has changed in the regex. So I had to correct some of the tests: https://regexr.com/7qlaq  Thank you for spending time on this, you're a regex God. So some of them like `foo(v.top)` it matches the whole thing but I'm only looking to match `v.top` or like if there's spaces ahead of it.

Comment: @Theodore All tests pass like this `^(?!(?:.*[^$])?\bs[^\w.]*t[^\w.]*y[^\w.]*l[^\w.]*e[^\w.]*\.top\b).*\.top\b.*` See https://regexr.com/7qlbi and see this regex demo for getting the value in a capture group (highlighted in green) https://regex101.com/r/XItiST/1

Comment: Let me try reuse the way you wrote the style match but some for example `foo(v.top)` I only want to match the `v.top`

Comment: @Theodore Yes, but then you have to get the group 1 value like here https://regex101.com/r/XItiST/1 But do you want a single match in a line? Or also multiple matches? Do you need a regex only, or can you also use code? And if you can have multiple matches, can you create a regex101 demo link and share it here with the expected matches?

Comment: One match only. No code. So yes, group 1 would make sense including $ and _ in the group 1.

Comment: @Theodore With the leading dollar sign in the group https://regex101.com/r/uI61iL/1

Comment: How would you remove the beginning text and brackets? I can remove the trailing text by removing `.*` at the end. But I'm kinda confused with the regex in the beginning.